# Two-Layer Neural Network in PyTorch does not Converge

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

## Problem

I am trying to implement 2-layer neural network using different methods (TensorFlow, PyTorch and from scratch) and then compare their performance based on MNIST dataset.

I am not sure what mistakes I have made, but the accuracy in PyTorch is only about 10%, which is basically random guess. I think probably the weights does not get updated at all.

Note that I intentionally use the dataset provided by TensorFlow to keep the data I use through 3 different methods consistent for accurate comparison.

```py
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import torch

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 =  torch.nn.Linear(784, 100)
      self.fc2 =  torch.nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
      # x -> (batch_size, 784)
      x = torch.relu(x)
      # x -> (batch_size, 10)
      x = torch.softmax(x, dim=1)
      return x

net = Net()
net.zero_grad()
Loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer =  torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(1000):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist_m.train.next_batch(100)
    # convert to appropriate settins
    # note the input to the linear layer should be (n_sample, n_features)
    batch_xs = torch.tensor(batch_xs, requires_grad=True)
    # batch_ys -> (batch_size,)
    batch_ys = torch.tensor(batch_ys, dtype=torch.int64)

    # forward
    # output -> (batch_size, 10)
    output = net(batch_xs)
    # result -> (batch_size,)
    result = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
    loss = Loss(output, batch_ys)

    # backward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't apply your fully connected layers `fc1` and `fc2`.

Your `forward()` currently looks like:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    # x -> (batch_size, 784)
    x = torch.relu(x)
    # x -> (batch_size, 10)
    x = torch.softmax(x, dim=1)
    return x
```

So if you change it to:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    # x -> (batch_size, 784)
    x = self.fc1(x)             # added layer fc1
    x = torch.relu(x)  

    # x -> (batch_size, 10)
    x = self.fc2(x)             # added layer fc2
    x = torch.softmax(x, dim=1)
    return x
```

It should work.

*Regarding Umang Guptas answer: As I see it, calling `zero_grad()` before calling `backward()` as Mr.Robot did, is just fine. This shouldn't be a problem.*

---

**Edit:**

So I did a short test - I set iterations from `1000` to `10000` to see the bigger picture if it is really decreasing. *( Of course I also loaded the data to `mnist_m` as this wasn't included in the code you've posted )*

I added a print condition to the code:

```py
if epoch % 1000 == 0:
    print('Epoch', epoch, '- Loss:', round(loss.item(), 3))
```

Which prints out the loss every `1000` iterations:

```py
Epoch 0 - Loss: 2.305
Epoch 1000 - Loss: 2.263
Epoch 2000 - Loss: 2.187
Epoch 3000 - Loss: 2.024
Epoch 4000 - Loss: 1.819
Epoch 5000 - Loss: 1.699
Epoch 6000 - Loss: 1.699
Epoch 7000 - Loss: 1.656
Epoch 8000 - Loss: 1.675
Epoch 9000 - Loss: 1.659
```

*Tested with PyTorch version 0.4.1*

So you can see that with the changed `forward()` the network is learning now, the rest of the code I left untouched.

Good luck further!

Comment: I didn't know you could `zero_grad` before step. Thank!

Comment: @UmangGupta It is no problem, because new gradients are created when calling `backward()`. So both versions you proposed are actually equivalent because of the loop *(after the loop is before the loop :-)* . What doesn't work is this order: `backward`-> `zero_grad` -> `step`, because then indeed gradients are zero when doing the *step*. Hope this makes sense to you! :)

Comment: I thought zero_grad would clear the computation graph and hence backward will have no effect. I am confused now what does zero_grad actually do.

Comment: @UmangGupta the gradient value is accumulated every time you backprop , 
so `optimizer.zero_grad()` tries to zero out previously accumulated gradient value and you could get the actual gradient instead of sum of history. You could check out [autograd doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html) for more information.